# Get stock/company names from Yahoo Finance using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The whole code is trying to get historical data from Yahoo Finance using VBA. Everything works pretty fine except the code whereby I try to get the company's name using from the Yahoo site.

This first piece of code is just to chceck that there are no mistakes in the definition in variables or whatever.

```
Enum READYSTATE
READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum

Sub GetData()
    Dim datasheet As Worksheet
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim symbol As String
    Dim qurl As String
    Dim nQuery As Name
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim ohtml As HTMLText

On Error GoTo error_getdata

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Set datasheet = ActiveSheet

    StartDate = datasheet.Range("startDate").Value
    EndDate = datasheet.Range("endDate").Value
    symbol = datasheet.Range("ticker").Value
    symbol = UCase(symbol)

    'Download data from Yahoo Finance'
    Sheets("Home").Activate
    Sheets(symbol).Range("a1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents

    qurl = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" & symbol
    qurl = qurl & "&a=" & Month(StartDate) - 1 & "&b=" & Day(StartDate) & _
            "&c=" & Year(StartDate) & "&d=" & Month(EndDate) - 1 & "&e=" & _
            Day(EndDate) & "&f=" & Year(EndDate) & "&g=" & Sheets(symbol).Range("a1") & "&q=q&y=0&z=" & _
            symbol & "&x=.csv"
    eurl = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & symbol & "?ltr=2"
```

Here is where the problem spots. I try to scrap the html of the site looking for the company's name. If I look at the html code of the website, I find that the company's name is labeled as *reactid="239"*. I guess that what I have to do is to use *getelementsbyID("239")* but I am not sure about that.

```
   '''''
Dim objIe As Object

Set objIe = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIe.Visible = False
objIe.navigate eurl
    Application.StatusBar = "Looking for information in Yahoo Finance"
While (objIe.Busy Or objIe.READYSTATE <> 4): DoEvents: Wend
Set xobj = objIe.querySelectorAll("[reactid=239]")
Debug.Print xobj.innerText
Set xobj = Nothing
objIe.Quit
Set objIe = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = ""

'Sort the existence of a ticker in our sheet and create a new one ' 
    Dim worksh As Integer
    Dim worksheetexists As Boolean
    Dim x As Integer
    worksh = Application.Sheets.Count
    worksheetexists = False
    For x = 1 To worksh
        If Worksheets(x).Name = symbol Then
            worksheetexists = True
            Sheets(symbol).Delete
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = symbol
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x
    If worksheetexists = False Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = symbol
    End If

' Load data '
QueryQuote:
    With Sheets(symbol).QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl, Destination:=Sheets(symbol).Range("a1"))
      .BackgroundQuery = True
      .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
      .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
      .SaveData = True
    End With

    Sheets(symbol).Range("a1").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=Sheets(symbol).Range("a1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
                Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=False

    Sheets(symbol).Columns("A:G").ColumnWidth = 12

    'Sort data'
    LastRow = Sheets(symbol).UsedRange.Row - 2 + Sheets(symbol).UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Sheets(symbol).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With Sheets(symbol).Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:G" & LastRow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
        .SortFields.Clear
    End With
Exit Sub

error_getdata:
    MsgBox ("Fatal error. Please insert a valid sticker for the stock")  
End Sub
```

I heed that this could not be the most efficient way to get what I want. First I want to learn how to get it done and then I will take on the efficiency of the program.

Edit: Using some answers, I edited a bit the code, it still shows up an error (error 438) on the line:

```
Set xobj = objIe.querySelectorAll("[reactid=239]")
```

Comment: `getElementsByID()` will only work for `id = "ExampleID"` attributes, `reactid` would not be classed as an `id` attribute by the `getElementsByID()` method

Comment: And what method whould should class the `reactid`?

Comment: in "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" & symbol
. Can you give us an example of symbol?

Comment: What HTML library are you using?  Please specify the Tools References of your project or are you exclusively using late binding?

Comment: `symbol`is the ticker of the company. AAPL, KO, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look into using http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp

which can allow selection of nodes using CSS selector syntax and there is a reference for this syntax at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

So perhaps something along the lines of

```
document.querySelectorAll("[reactid=239]")
```

Incidentally, you can browse the library if you use a Tools Reference to

```
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: It didn't work, but I learned other things thanks to your answer.

Comment: @Alejandro Jiménez Rico : hmmm, yes I have confirmed bug running your code.  Silly Microsoft!  This is supposed to be HTML5 feature and it looks broken.  However `objIe.document.querySelectorAll("h1").Item(6).innerText` gives Company name.  You could get all the h1 tags and loop through to defend against document structure change.